# How to avoid to use setTimeout in angualrjs DOM handiling

Tags: angularjs, dom

I have one dataset. I am populating  items based on that dataset.

Here, data is populating fine. after that, i am trying to do dom operation.

I couldn't able to do DOM operation without using setTimeout.

How can i do this without setTimeout?

```
var allElLi = angular.element('.listview-li');
            var selEl = angular.element('.listview-li')[0];
            $(allElLi).removeClass('item-active');
            $(selEl).addClass('item-active');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MohaideenIsmail/Lvc0u55v/6892/

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/MohaideenIsmail/Lvc0u55v/6892/
```

Comment: What you are doing is sure way to really bad jQuery-style application. If you care about quality and maintainability - learn how to do it Angular way. For starters remove jQuery from the project until you understand why you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

dfsq is right in his answer but could have been a little more helpful. You should not be doing dom manipulation in your controller, use a directive. Read this post and you should be fine: http://ng-learn.org/2014/01/Dom-Manipulations/

Key here is that directives have 'link' function which get's fired after the html has been compiled. Directives can be hard at first but you should really take your time to get to know them!